# JOIN and REPLACE in Pig

Tags: apache-pig

I am  having 2 bags

```
A=
1,Anju,P,3.6,IT,A,1.6,0.3
2,Remya,P,3.3,EEE,B,1.6,0.3

B=
1,5.3
2,4.9
```

I am trying to replace "P" in each tuple with the values in next bag

```
1,Anju,5.3,3.6,IT,A,1.6,0.3
2,Remya,4.9,3.3,EEE,B,1.6,0.3
```

Tried using JOIN

```
1,Anju,P,3.6,IT,A,1.6,0.3,1,5.3
2,Remya,P,3.3,EEE,B,1.6,0.3,2,4.9
```

But am I able to use any thing similar to `WHERE` Clause.

```
jnd = JOIN A by $0,B by $0 --where P in each tuple replace with value in B
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use JOIN and the project fields in the desired order using FOREACH ... GENERATE

```
JND = JOIN A by $0, B BY $0;
JND = FOREACH JND GENERATE $0, $1, $9, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7;
```

I suggest you use names for fields when loading data. It makes everything easier

Comment: Yes But this will be static right? I am trying to reuse my pigscript

Comment: What do you exactly mean?

Comment: Sory.What I meant is if we are writing scripts like that It can be only used to that specific input.What if the input contains more than 11 fields.We need to manually add upto $10 right.

Comment: You can always, project until the end like this:

   JND = FOREACH JND GENERATE $0, $1, $9, $3 ..;

However, I think that $9 will be repeated in your dataset :(

Comment: Can we do that using replace along with join

Comment: There is a REPLACE operator for strings, but not for fields. We could delete the content of the column, but the column would be still there. I am afraid there is no operator for that, but let us hope that I am mistaken.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50850/discussion-between-sreeveni-and-vicsana1)